# Custom global javascript event dispatcher

Tags: javascript, global, dispatch

I am trying to create a custom event dispatcher. I have read [this](https://medium.com/@muhammad_hamada/simple-event-dispatcher-implementation-using-javascript-36d0eadf5a11) article and implemented the code

```js
export default class Dispatcher{
    constructor(){

    }

    addListener (event, callback) {
        // Check if the callback is not a function
        if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
            console.error(`The listener callback must be a function, the given type is ${typeof callback}`);
            return false;
        }
        // Check if the event is not a string
        if (typeof event !== 'string') {
            console.error(`The event name must be a string, the given type is ${typeof event}`);
            return false;
        }
            
        // Create the event if not exists
        if (this.events[event] === undefined) {
            this.events[event] = {
                listeners: []
            }
        }
            
        this.events[event].listeners.push(callback);
    }

    removeListener(event, callback){
        //check if this event not exists
        if(this.events[event] === undefined){
            console.error(`This event: ${event} does not exist`);
            return false;
        }

        this.events[event].listeners = this.events[event].listeners.filter(listener => {
            return listener.toString() !== callback.toString();
        })
    }

    dispatch(event, details){
        //check if this event not exists
        if(this.events[event] === undefined){
            console.error(`This event: ${event} does not exist`);
            return false;
        }

        this.events[event].listeners.forEach((listener) => {
            listener(details);
        })
    }
}
```

my goal is for my external classes that I import into my main JavaScript file to be able to dispatch events globaly. so i want my js imported like this

```js
import {API2} from '/js/API2.js'
```

to be able to dispatch an event that can be captured from the `main.js` file that originally imports the `API2` class.

one way that I have tried is to attach the imported dispatcher class to `window` but this is obviously wrong and produces no result.

How could one implement a dispatcher class that allows me to add events and dispatch events globally from anywhere in the code imported or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want 2 things:

1. Import the dispatcher into a file and use the class directly
2. Use a global object to interact with the class

## 1. import into a file and use it directly

In order to import it directly and use it, create a `singleton` (so 1 instance of the class) and export it directly:

```
class Dispatcher{
   ...
}

export default new Dispatcher() // this will initialise the singleton instantly
```

In order to use it, you can now import it in any file:

```
 import dispatcher from './dispatcher.js';
```

It will be the same instance anywhere.

## 2. make it global

In order to make it global you could actually update the file with the following (either `global` for nodejs or `window` for web):

```
class Dispatcher{
   ...
}

const dispatcherSingleton = new Dispatcher();

window.dispatcherSingleton = dispatcherSingleton // web
global.dispatcherSingleton = dispatcherSingleton // nodejs

export default dispatcherSingleton // export the singleton
```

Comment: Excellent answer thank you so much.